# print word from database

Tags: python, mysql

I have a text file 'hi.txt' which has :

```
i have a friend whosr name is win.And has  a friend who is great.
```

I have a database table testtb as

```
testid test1
1      hello
2      hi
3      friend
4      great
5      win
```

i want to print the output as:

3    friendy
5    win
4    greatl

I want to print the similar words for all the line using the Full text indexing.It is used not only for the given example so donot answer limiting this example alone.Please answer!

I created a program as:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila")
```

keyword=[]

```
with open('qwer2.txt','r') as file, db as cursor:
    for line in file:


        if key in keywords:
            print j#<-need to print the row that is matched

cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Now change your password.

Comment: means mysql is not a secure password^^

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do a levenshtein-distance search on a mySql database. If someone knows a possibility how to do it, I would be interested to know too. However, you could iterate over the complete database and search for similar words with the following algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm